# ошибка расшифровки строки AES

Tags: c#, aes

Шифрование:

```
static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_AES(string plainText, string password, string salt, string hashAlg,
                                                                                int passIter, string initialVector, int keySize)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(plainText) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(salt) ||
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hashAlg) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(initialVector)) return null;

    byte[] initialVectorBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initialVector);
    byte[] saltValueBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

    PasswordDeriveBytes derivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes
     (password, saltValueBytes, hashAlg, passIter);

    byte[] keyBytes = derivedPassword.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    byte[] encrypted;

    ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initialVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    encrypted = memStream.ToArray();
    memStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    symmetricKey.Clear();

    return (encrypted);
}
```

Вызываю следующим образом

```
byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_AES(_view.InputContent, _view.Pass, _view.Salt, "SHA1", _view.NumIter, _view.InitVector, 256);
```

Работает. Не работает расшифровка (вызываемая `string decrypted = DecryptStringFromBytes_AES(_view.InputContent, _view.Pass, _view.Salt, "SHA1", _view.NumIter, _view.InitVector, 256);`)

Сам код:

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytes_AES(string cipherText, string password, string salt, string hashAlg,
                                                                                int passIter, string initialVector, int keySize)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cipherText) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(salt) ||
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hashAlg) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(initialVector)) return null;

    byte[] initialVectorBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initialVector);
    byte[] saltValueBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    PasswordDeriveBytes derivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltValueBytes, hashAlg, passIter);
    byte[] keyBytes = derivedPassword.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
    int byteCount = 0;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor();
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    byteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    memStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();

    symmetricKey.Clear();

    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, byteCount);
}
```

Выдает такой стектрейс:

> в System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
>      в System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
>      в System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      в MyEncryptor.MainPresenter`1.DecryptStringFromBytes_AES(String cipherText, String password, String salt, String hashAlg, Int32 passIter, String initialVector, Int32 keySize) в e:\IT\GITreps\MyExamples\MVCexample\MyEncryptor\MainPresenter.cs:строка 227
>      в MyEncryptor.MainPresenter`1._view_FileOpenClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) в e:\IT\GITreps\MyExamples\MVCexample\MyEncryptor\MainPresenter.cs:строка 128

Ошибка в строке

> byteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

Может подскажет кто, что я не так сваял?

Comment: А какое исключение-то?

Comment: заполнение неверно и не может быть удалено.

Comment: проблема решена.

Comment: Тогда, может, напишете ответ? Чтобы потомки смогли получить пользу, если у них возникнет подобная проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я проводил лишние приведения. Рабочий код привожу ниже. Шифрование:

```
public string Encrypt_AES_String(string input, string passPhrase, string saltValue, string hashString, int Iterations, string initVect, int keySize)
{
    byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVect);
    byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashString, Iterations);

    byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);

    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
}
```

Вызываю следующим образом:

```
string encrypted = _crypter.Encrypt_AES_String(input, _view.Pass, _view.Salt, "SHA1", _view.NumIter, _view.InitVector, 256);
```

Расшифровка:

```
public string Decrypt_AES_String(string input, string passPhrase, string saltValue, string hashAlgorithm,int Iterations, string initVector, int keySize)
{
    byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
    byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, Iterations);

    byte[] keyBytes =  password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);

    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);

    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length + 1];

    int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();

    string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
    return plainText;
}
```

Вызываю следующим образом:

```
string decrypted = _crypter.Decrypt_AES_String(input, _view.Pass, _view.Salt,"SHA1", _view.NumIter, _view.InitVector, 256);
```

Comment: Может быть кто нибудь знает как к этому делу прикрутить progressbar?